# Updating Database via GET request to Generic views in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I've got this Generic view that would list records from my DB for `GET` request to `localhost:8000` However, I also want to UPDATE those records upon `GET`. For instance, `GET` `localhost:8000` would return a list like so:

```
[
    {
        "user": 1,
        "address": "sdfgasgasdfg",
        "balance": "123.00000000"
    },
    {
        "user": 1,
        "address": "sdfgasgasdfg25",
        "balance": "123.00000000"
    }
]
```

Upon GET, I would like to also make an API to https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api to get the latest BTC balance and update the balance values for those addresses in my DB. Not quite sure how to do so with generic views

view

```
class WalletListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer
```

model

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=8)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=34, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.address)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: GET request is only for fetching data not updating or creating, the best thing to do here is to have a background tasks fetch the API every few minutes to get the latest balance and then store it in the database, that way your user will always get the latest balance and you won't have to perform a create or update action a GET request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would override the `list(...)` method of the API (which is getting called on GET request)

```py
class WalletListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer

    def pull_data_from_api_and_update_db(self):
        # do some stuff here
        pass

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pull_data_from_api_and_update_db()
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here, you can add/update the `pull_data_from_api_and_update_db(...)` method the way you wish to.